# is it possible to rewrite dir using .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am wondering whether it's possible to use .htaccess to rewrite a folder name. What I mean is this.

Lets say user type url in the browser:

```
https://example.com/categoryxxx/dir1/dir2/?param=aaa#hash=xxx
```

In the background (server):

This (root/categoryxxx/dir1/dir2/) is not exist.

This folder exist instead (root/dir1/dir2/categoryxxx/)

so the request gets pass to that folder instead.

user still see this url in their browser (nothing change for the user):

```
https://example.com/categoryxxx/dir1/dir2/?param=aaa#hash=xxx
```

1. how to do this in htaccess? if its not possible any other method to make it possible?
2. will my php [REQUEST_URI] return the user typed-in or the file in the server? is it possible to make it way around?

Note:
its not just examplecom/categoryxxx/dir1/dir2/ it can be examplecom/categoryxxx/dir1/dir2/dir3 (the number of dir is random)

Comment: This sounds as if you have not read any tutorial about request rewriting, not read the documentation, not looked at any examples. Why not? Don't get this wrong, I am not trying to mock you or anything. But please understand that there are endless explanations for exactly what you ask here. Still you ask the question if it is possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(categoryxxx)((?:/(?:[^/]+))+)/?$ /$2/$1 [END,QSA]
```

Implementing such a rewrite rule will *not* alter the entry in the superglobal php variable `$_REQUEST`. So `$_REQUEST['REQUEST_URI']` will *still* contain "/categoryxxx/dir1/dir2/" which definitely makes sense.

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Hi, thanks. but this doesnt work. it will rewrite other folder to0. not just 'categoryxxx'

Comment: and please look at the note. sounds easy when you read the title. but its not that simple when you read the bottom note.

Comment: I updated the mathcing pattern to accept arbitrary path levels following the initial folder.

Comment: And another update fixes the actual folder name "categoryxxx" (that is what I understood from your comment, though I fail to understand the "0"). Before I understood the question such that also the first folder name was arbitrary.

Comment: Hi thank you.
It almost work. But still showing 404

Because it fecth this internally (which is not exist):
ROOT/dir1/dir2/?param1=value1

What I want is:
ROOT/dir1/dir2/categoryxxx/?param1=value1

So the 'categoryxxx' changed from "1st part" of dir path to the "last part" of dir path

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the brackets around that fixed folder name in the pattern. Fixed in the answer.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much its working now.
I improved your version by adding slash to the '/$2/$1/'. will it cause a problem? . Because your version result 'ROOT/dir1/dir2/categoryxxx' will get redirected to 'ROOT/dir1/dir2/categoryxxx/' by default in apache.
And if you can please fix your answer. There is no such thing like 'RequestCond' and 'Rewrite rule' the correct command is 'RewriteCond' and 'RewriteRule'.

Comment: The addition of a trailing slash actually is _not_ a default in the apache http server, it is an additional module performing that change. If it is installed and configured on your system then it certainly does make sense to immediately rewrite to a path including a trailing slash as you now did.